# R - run system call with space in path on Mac

Tags: r, macos, directory, space

I am trying to invoke some system commands on R using `system()` calls. However, I am having the infamous problem with spaces in the directories.

For example, I am trying to use this directory:

```
odir <- '/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/data/cmip5/historical/clt/models'
```

on this command:

```
system(paste('ls ', odir,sep=''))
```

and I receive the following error:

```
> system(paste('ls ', odir,sep=''))
ls: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
ls: 2/data/cmip5/historical/clt/models: No such file or directory
ls: HD: No such file or directory
```

How can I overcome this?

Thanks!

Comment: One might have expected that the second space also needed a double-backslash.

Comment: You are correct. I detected it and corrected on my code, but it would be nice if @MrFlick could edit his post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most command lines require that you escape spaces with a backslash. And when you make R strings, you need to escape backslashes with a backslash. Try

```
odir <- '/Volumes/Macintosh\\ HD\\ 2/data/cmip5/historical/clt/models'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrFlick! Although it was a pretty simple solution, I just couldn't find the right answer.